# Is it OK to swallow all exceptions except the critical ones in certain scenarios?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

There are certain scenarios where I just want to call a certain method to do some work and don't care about handling all specific exceptions it can throw. Instead, all I really care is if the method succeeded or not.

I will provide a .NET / C# example. Let's say I have a file that I want to copy and all I really care is whether copy operation was successful or not. If copying failed I don't care if particular exception was FileNotFoundException or an IOException "Not enough disk space" exception or something else... My application will move on normally in that case as this operation is not critical.

So the idea how to implement this is:

```cs
try 
{
  // try 
  System.IO.File.Copy(strFile, strFile + ".new");
} 
catch (Exception ex) 
{
  // if critical exception then rethrow
  if (IsCritical(ex)) 
      throw;

  // else just log and swallow...
  Console.WriteLine("Failed to copy the file: " + ex.Message);
}
```

where IsCritical(Exception ex) is helper method defined as:

```cs
public static bool IsCritical(Exception ex) 
{
  if (ex is OutOfMemoryException) return true;
  if (ex is AppDomainUnloadedException) return true;
  if (ex is BadImageFormatException) return true;
  if (ex is CannotUnloadAppDomainException) return true;
  if (ex is ExecutionEngineException) return true;
  if (ex is InvalidProgramException) return true;
  if (ex is System.Threading.ThreadAbortException) 
      return true;
  return false;
}
```

This question is based on following article: [Exception Handling in C# with the "Do Not Catch Exceptions That You Cannot Handle" rule in mind](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7557/Exception-Handling-in-C-with-the-quot-Do-Not-Catch)

The idea is to follow the main rules of exception handling best practices:
- don't catch general Exception without rethrowing
- catch only exceptions you know how to handle - (in this case I want to handle them all in the same way... by logging and moving on with the application logic).

So is this a good approach for the given scenario? If not, why and what would be better thing to do?

Comment: Personally, I would replace `Console.WriteLine("Failed to copy the file: " + ex.Message);` by a call to a decent logging framework (log4net, NLog, you name it) to be sure to have _much more_ information being logged like stack trace etc.

Comment: The problem is, you've enumerated two sets of exceptions - the ones that you think are critical and the ones (currently FileNotFoundException and IOException) that you're sure are benign. But there are surely *lots* of exceptions that are currently in *neither* of your lists. Are you sure that they all fall into the benign category? If not, surely they should be (without any other knowledge) treated the same as the critical ones?

Comment: Not a .Net guy but the way this is done in Java is that they made a difference between Exceptions and Errors ( both extending Throwable ) where Errors are for example OutOfMemoryError and Exceptions are all application level errors; ie IOException. This is why they say never catch Throwable ( Unless you really know what youre doing ) which is basically what the referenced article is saying.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The reason it is generally advised to not swallow exceptions is that it can hide bugs. For example, you are doing something other than doing a `File.Copy`: you are doing string processing as well (`strFile + ".new"`). This cannot throw (except for OOM), but if the calculation was more complex, **you might have hidden a bug**.

In this case you should probably move all calculations out of the try-block. Then it is OK to swallow any exceptions. I'm in the habit of logging them in case I still made a mistake despite being careful.

The rule to not swallow needlessly is there to protect the developer from his own fallibility. If you are reasonably sure that everything is alright then you don't need to follow the rule.

Answer (score 9):

This line worries me a little...

> If copying failed I don't care if particular exception was FileNotFoundException or an IOException "Not enough disk space" exception or something else

Not so much the FNF exception but more with the "*Not enough disk space*" etc. - these are the sort of exceptions you probably don't want to ignore. Reason being, if there isn't enough disk space then, in theory, your app is going to fail *eventually*. This is actually one of the main reasons you *shouldn't* catch general exceptions because you effectively mask bigger problems like these.

On a more general note, and to answer your question more specifically, it's perfectly fine to catch a more general exception where you are confident it won't have any major implications with your app nor, as mentioned previously (and I re-iterate for good reason), won't mask any bigger/more serious issues.

Comment: Good points, on the other hand handling all possible failures is rarely done in practice anyway because the effort is not justified. I guess few programs handle a disk full condition (and rightly so).

Comment: @usr yeah, I am by no means saying you should handle these sort of issues *every* time. However, my concern was how "lax" the OP seemed to be about the fact that these sort of exceptions were being overlooked.

Comment: "if there isn't enough disk space then, in theory, your app is going to fail eventually" - this is false statement. If operation failed, you warn user, user cleans up space, you repeat copying and it success. Another case - you are copying to a network - network fails, user can fix and repeat, similar to Http/WebException.

Comment: @EvgenyGorbovoy the point was the OP was not considering these types of errors as important and looking to swallow them. I'm not saying those errors aren't fixable but you can only fix problems you are made aware of...

Comment: @James Ok, it's just in my opinion that and next sentences are spoiling the answer, but the answer is better than the accepted one.

Answer (score 6):

It's okay to swallow *specific* exceptions in particular cases, but in practice it depends on the use case.

I recommend handling exceptions, you *can* handle and use the [AppDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event for unhandled exceptions and inform the user about what happened.

From a debugging perspective it doesn't really matter, as long as you have access to the code, since you can enable to break on all common runtime exceptions in Visual Studio. (Debug -> Exceptions -> Common Language Runtime Exceptions -> Check the left checkbox)

I would never depend on a list of critical exceptions, because you don't really know if the list is complete.

Comment: The last statement is very true. It would be better to consider some exceptions non-critical (can be swallowed) and all other exceptions (the mentioned ones + the "unexpected") shouldn't be swallowed.

Answer (score 1):

It is ok to **swallow** exceptions if you want your program to be undebuggable and admins to hate you.

You need to at least log the exceptions at a lower log level `debug`, `trace`, `fine` or whatever.

It will help in debugging issues, understanding how program works, or why something didn't happen.

The only exceptions that can be swallowed are these that absolutely don't have effect on the app which are very rare (e.g. sleep interrupted exception). See this [nice article](https://fishbowl.pastiche.org/2003/04/28/swallowing_exceptions_dont_do_it).

Now in your example you are not completely swallowing exception but printing message while discarding the stacktrace.

Just make sure that exception message contains information about source and destination of copying so that this can be debugged by the user. Also depending on your app, it might be useful to know which part of the app code is doing the copying. Sometimes it might be needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can add several catch statements for the same try:

```
try
{
 //code here
}
 catch (FileNotFoundException ex1) 
{
  //Do whatever you want
}
catch (IOException ex2)
{
  //Do whatever you want
}
```

I suggest to handle the exception that you don't consider critical and for all the remaining one
do just one `catch  (Exception er){throw ;}`

Also Just for this two specific exception is enough just to catch an `IOException`, because `IOException` is the `FileNotFountException`'s parent class

Comment: I cannot see how this answers the question. Plus: `catch (Exception er){throw er;}` makes no sense at all to me.

Comment: `throw er;` shouldn't be used to re-throw exceptions, it destroys the previous call stack in the exception and restarts it. You should use `throw;` instead.

Comment: Yes you are right, he can avoid the catch(Exception er) was just for give hime the idea

Comment: @ChrisMantle `catch (Exception er){throw ;}` makes as much sense to me: None. This would be the same as simply omitting the whole line altogether.

Comment: @UweKeim It was more of a general comment. You're right, it makes no sense to catch and re-throw without doing anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I think you answered you question yourself. It is entirely depends on your business logic. But generally if I would "swallow" exception but only by their particular type as, again, you did just in another way.

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to say that any exception that comes from code you did not write yourself *should* be treated as a critical exception, since it means that the system that threw the error is could well be in an undefined state and therefore any subsequent operations you attempt on that system can't be guaranteed to succeed.

Therefore I'd probably do something like:

```
  try 
    {
      System.IO.File.Copy(strFile, strFile + ".new");
     //MyLibrary throws exception clases I defined so I know what they are all about
      MyLibrary.SomeClass.DoSomething(strFile);
    }
    catch(ExceptionTypeIDefinedInMyLibraryWhichIKnowICanSafelyIgnore iex)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Not to worry: "+ iex.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
      //This absolute is not something I can handle. Log it and throw.
      Log(ex); throw;
    }
```

This way you cannot ignore critical exceptions, and you can only ever throw a specific type of exception from your own sub-systems because you're in control of what they throw.

However if you really wanted to follow the pattern you demonstrated, I'd be inclined to turn this around and only deal with exceptions you know you *can* handle, and throw everything else.

That way you won't be burned when a new `OhMyGodThereAreZombiesInTheServer` exception gets added to the BCL, you never know, it could happen...

i.e

```
try 
{
  // try 
  System.IO.File.Copy(strFile, strFile + ".new");
} 
catch (Exception ex) 
{
  // if critical exception then rethrow
  if (ICanHandleThis(ex)) 
  {
   Console.WriteLine("Failed to copy the file: " + ex.Message);
  }
  else
  {
   //step aside and let Dr McNinja deal with it
   throw;
  }     
}

public static bool ICanHandleThis(Exception ex) 
{
 //I don't care about these exceptions, they aren't critical
 //to my application for some reason.
 return (ex is SomeTrivialExceptionTypeIDontCareAbout 
        || ex is SomeOtherIgnorableExceptionType);

}
```